# Microsoft Graph API returns deleted objects

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to retrieve places using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/{id}
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/{id}
```

It successfully retrieves the place wanted.

If I remove the room using Remove-Mailbox (PowerShell cmdlet), Graph API request keeps retrieving the deleted room even after several hours.

Is this behavior by design ? How do I "refresh" data get by Graph API ?

Thanks

Comment: It's strange. And I tried to find answer from Ms document but failed. So I want to post some of my idea and wish it will help. First, I think you can make sure whether the room has really been removed. Then if you can point those items which are removed from the Api response, take using **$filter** into consideration. Perhaps you can compare them with those are not removed and got the differences in parameter(maybe there won't be some parameters to show which one is removed).

Comment: I see that you used Remove-mailbox cmdlet, but with which parameters you tried it? It matters a lot. For your scenario, I would suggest you to use the Identity and Permanent parameters to disconnect the mailbox from the user, remove the user account, and immediately remove the mailbox from the mailbox database. The mailbox doesn't remain in the mailbox database as a disconnected mailbox. Once you're done then give sometime for exchange to replicate the changes, then try make the above Graph API call, then see if it works or still you have the issue.

Comment: In case if you used Identity parameter alone to disconnect the mailbox from the user and remove the user account then, the mailbox still exists. It is retained until the deleted mailbox retention period expires - i think it happening in your scenario. The deleted mailbox retention period is controlled by the MailboxRetention property on the mailbox database or on the mailbox itself if the UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults property is False.

Comment: Does the above helped?

Comment: Yes, it worked. I used the "PermanentlyDelete" parameter and made sure it was not part of the "SoftDeleted" mailboxes anymore. 
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Wow, glad to hear.

Comment: @a1mery I will move this to answer. Please consider upvoting it; so it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I see that you used Remove-mailbox cmdlet, but with which parameters you tried it? It matters a lot. For your scenario, I would suggest you to use the Identity and Permanent parameters to disconnect the mailbox from the user, remove the user account, and immediately remove the mailbox from the mailbox database. The mailbox doesn't remain in the mailbox database as a disconnected mailbox. Once you're done then give sometime for exchange to replicate the changes, then try make the above Graph API call, then see if it works or still you have the issue.
- In case if you used Identity parameter alone to disconnect the mailbox from the user and remove the user account then, the mailbox still exists. It is retained until the deleted mailbox retention period expires - i think it happening in your scenario. The deleted mailbox retention period is controlled by the MailboxRetention property on the mailbox database or on the mailbox itself if the UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults property is False
- You tried the same and confirmed that you used the "PermanentlyDelete" parameter and made sure it was not part of the "SoftDeleted" mailboxes anymore.